# Listview only displaying last item of arraylist

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I have a problem. Currently i'm using Lazyloading to load images and data into my listview using arraylist. However it only display the last item of the arraylist.

Below is the LazyLoading adapter class:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView title;
    public TextView author;
    public TextView format;
    public TextView call_number;
    public ImageView cover_image;

    public Button next;
    public Button previous;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result_display_list , null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();

        holder.next = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.next);
        holder.previous = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.previous);

        holder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        holder.author = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_author);
        holder.format = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_format);
        holder.call_number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_call_number);
        holder.cover_image=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.cover_image);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        vi = convertView;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
        holder.title.setText(data.get(i).get("title"));
        holder.author.setText(data.get(i).get("author"));
        holder.format.setText(data.get(i).get("format"));
        holder.call_number.setText(data.get(i).get("callNumber"));
        holder.cover_image.setTag(data.get(i).get("coverImage"));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(i).get("coverImage"), activity, holder.cover_image);
    }
    return vi;
}
```

I'm thinking that the problem might actually be with my for-loop. Where it is being generated infinitely. But I don't know where did I go wrong in typing this code. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the for loop and in place of i in `data.get(i)` use `position`

Comment: Oh my god. It works! Been staring at this error for hours and I didn't even think of using position! Haha. Thanks!!!!