# For statement is only returning the last data when Passing Data Using Intent

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps, for-loop, android-intent

I want to pass data between Activities using Intents. I can already send the data but the problem is that the data only contains the last item.

I'm not sure but I think the problem is with the `for` statement based on the following references:

- [Parsing JSON to custom ArrayList, only returning last item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190012/parsing-json-to-custom-arraylist-only-returning-last-item)
- [Listview only displaying last item of arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013917/listview-only-displaying-last-item-of-arraylist)

Here is my code. I hope someone can help solve my issues.

```
private void getAllDataLocation() {
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Menampilkan Semua Tempat...", true, false);

    mApiService.getAllPartner().enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePartner>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponsePartner> call, Response<ResponsePartner> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                loading.dismiss();

                final List<PlaceItem> placeItems = response.body().getAllPlace();
                initMarker(placeItems);

            } else {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Gagal Mengambil Data Semua Tempat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponsePartner> call, Throwable t) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Koneksi Internet Bermasalah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
private void initMarker(final List<PlaceItem> listData) {
    //for each semua data dan tampilkan markernya
    for (int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++) {
        final int finall = i;
        //set latlng nya
        LatLng marker_location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(listData.get(i).getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(listData.get(i).getLongitude()));
        //tambah markernya
        marker_bg.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.marker_primary));
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().title(listData.get(i).getName()).position(marker_location);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Tools.createBitmapFromView(ActivityMaps.this, marker_view)));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        //start for marker specific zoom ex: for specific city you want to zoom
        LatLng marker_zoom_specific = new LatLng(Constant.city_lat, Constant.city_lng);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker_zoom_specific, 12));
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                String id = listData.get(finall).getId();
                String cityName = listData.get(finall).getCityName();
                String description = listData.get(finall).getDescription();
                String address = listData.get(finall).getAddress();
                String phone = listData.get(finall).getPhone();
                String website = listData.get(finall).getWebsite();
                String logo = listData.get(finall).getLogo();
                String toolbarTitle = listData.get(finall).getName();
                String latitude = listData.get(finall).getLatitude();
                String longitude = listData.get(finall).getLongitude();

                Intent toDetail = new Intent(ActivityMaps.this, ActivityPlaceDetail.class);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_ID_PARTNER, id);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_NAME, toolbarTitle);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_CITY_NAME, cityName);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_ADDRESS, address);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_PHONE, phone);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_WEBSITE, website);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_LOGO, logo);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);
                toDetail.putExtra(Constant.KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
                startActivity(toDetail);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to pass the whole class object rather than passing individual key-value pair.

```
     PlaceItem placeItem = listData.get(finall).getId();
     intent.putExtra("data", placeItem);
```

Make sure your ***PlaceItem*** implements ***Serializable***

And when you getIntent use :

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    PlaceItem placeItem = (PlaceItem) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
    String id = placeItem.getId();
    String cityName = placeItem.getCityName();
```

and so on..

Comment: I have problem when decralre PlaceItem placeItem = listData.get(finall).getId(); 
The message is : Required model PlaceItem. Found : Java.lang.String
what should i do?

Comment: And variable placeItem should declared final.

Comment: Here is my activity maps [ActivityMaps](https://pastebin.com/u9VKUc59) and activity place detail [ActivityPlaceDetail](https://pastebin.com/RA80pZ3Q)

Comment: @Kusnadi where is your  PlaceItem class ! Have you implemented with Serializable?

Comment: yes, i've impelement Serializable in PlaceItem class.

Comment: You can see on line 125 in ActivityMaps but its getting error as i said.

Comment: It is because **listData.get(finall).getId();** will return integer and you are storing it in the **PlaceItem**  object. That is wrong... Either you should write **int id  = listData.get(finall).getId();**  or you have to write **PlaceItem placeItem = listData.get(finall);**